# Does your equipment/weapons degrade?

Tags: destiny

My first piece of information on this topic came from the inventory item "Weapon parts" that you got from dismantling weapons.

*Weapon parts - used to upgrade and **repair** weapons.*

There is also the same descriptions for the three armour dismantled parts.

My second clue was that after a while, I noticed that my cloak (on my Warlock) had become tattered and soiled. I had sworn it was nice and crisp a few hours beforehand.

So my question is, does your equipment actually degrade? I haven't seen anything similar to durability, so is it only aesthetic?

Comment: The [Destiny wikia](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Parts) has the same description, but it doesn't seem to be something you can do as of yet?

Comment: The repair part might refer to the need to use those parts to "restore" exotic weapons to their former glory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to repair items and there doesn't seem to be any degrading factors in the game.

That being said, I have also noticed my armor visually degrading by getting scratched up and paint peeling slightly, though. That seems to be purely cosmetic based on its use/duration of ownership. It doesn't seem to affect stats in any way, and it probably won't until a repair system is implemented.

There might've been repair/durability stats in early development in the game and that description was just overlooked when the system was removed.

Comment: I thought as much. However I must say I do like the cosmetic aspect of it.

Comment: I've never noticed this on my titan.. does logging out and back in restore the degradation?  I feel like it would be noticeable by now since I've been wearing mostly the same legendaries for about a week now.

Comment: I never noticed this either. Meant to look today when I got on but then I found myself zoned out at the loot cave and forgot... I'll check tomorrow for sure.